# exc_bad_access when dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, dynamic-cast

```
CCArray* CommonTool::getChidrenRecursive(CCNode *parent)
{
    CCArray* children = parent->getChildren();
    CCArray* result = CCArray::create();
    const auto count = children->count();
    CCLOG("count = %d ", count);
    CCLOG("children = %p", children);
    for(auto index = 0 ; index < count ; index++) {
        CCLOG("index = %d", index);
        const auto c = children->objectAtIndex(index);
        CCLOG("c = %p", c);
        const auto& t = typeid(c);
        CCLOG("type = %s", t.name());
        const auto ccc = dynamic_cast<CCObject*>(c);
        CCLOG("ccc = %p", ccc);
        const auto childNode = dynamic_cast<CCNode*>(c); // <- EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs
```

Does anyone have experience with this?

If it can not be cast, NULL is returned.
If an exception occurs, std::bad_cast is thrown.
I want to know the conditions under which EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs instead of the above two cases.

I guess that pointer is probably wrong, but since dynamic_cast does not work, I can not investigate the type of pointer.
I would like you to tell me if there is a good way to investigate the type of pointer.

Comment: Use a debugger to catch the crash. Then it will help you tell you the type of the variable.

Comment: In this case, a variable can not be captured in the debugger(Xcode 8.2.1)

Comment: You can use use typeid to find the type of pointer of c: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid